# Figure in a figure in a figure

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I'm experimenting with `matplotlib` to draw figures in figures in figures. Since squares are the most straight-forward to draw, I started with those. In the end I want to write a generator for polygons with a certain width. In the given example, this would be a 4-corner polygon with straight angles and width 1.

My current code plots the following, which is as expected and almost as desired.

[image: square in square in square]

Note there is a line between `2,2` and `2,3` which I think can be removed if this is done with a correct algorithm instead of the current code.

A summary of the above is a square boxed in two boxes with an amplitude increasing with `1`, assuming the the larger boxes are 'behind' the rest of the boxes.

The method of which I wrote the code producing the above is, well, not really a function. It's a darn ugly collection of points which happen to resemble hollow squares.

```py
import matplotlib.path as mpath
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

INNER_AMPLITUDE = 1.0
OUTER_AMPLITUDE = 3.0

Path_in = mpath.Path
path_in_data = [
    (Path_in.MOVETO, (INNER_AMPLITUDE, -INNER_AMPLITUDE)),
    (Path_in.LINETO, (-INNER_AMPLITUDE, -INNER_AMPLITUDE)),
    (Path_in.LINETO, (-INNER_AMPLITUDE, INNER_AMPLITUDE)),
    (Path_in.LINETO, (INNER_AMPLITUDE, INNER_AMPLITUDE)),
    (Path_in.CLOSEPOLY, (INNER_AMPLITUDE, -INNER_AMPLITUDE)),
    ]
codes, verts = zip(*path_in_data)
path_in = mpath.Path(verts, codes)
patch_in = mpatches.PathPatch(path_in, facecolor='g', alpha=0.3)
ax.add_patch(patch_in)

x, y = zip(*path_in.vertices)
line, = ax.plot(x, y, 'go-')

Path_out = mpath.Path
path_out_data = [
    (Path_out.MOVETO, (OUTER_AMPLITUDE, -OUTER_AMPLITUDE)),
    (Path_out.LINETO, (-OUTER_AMPLITUDE, -OUTER_AMPLITUDE)),
    (Path_out.LINETO, (-OUTER_AMPLITUDE, OUTER_AMPLITUDE)),
    (Path_out.LINETO, (OUTER_AMPLITUDE, OUTER_AMPLITUDE)),
    (Path_out.LINETO, (OUTER_AMPLITUDE, OUTER_AMPLITUDE-INNER_AMPLITUDE)),
    (Path_out.LINETO, (-(OUTER_AMPLITUDE-INNER_AMPLITUDE), OUTER_AMPLITUDE-INNER_AMPLITUDE)),
    (Path_out.LINETO, (-(OUTER_AMPLITUDE-INNER_AMPLITUDE), -(OUTER_AMPLITUDE-INNER_AMPLITUDE))),
    (Path_out.LINETO, (OUTER_AMPLITUDE-INNER_AMPLITUDE, -(OUTER_AMPLITUDE-INNER_AMPLITUDE))),
    (Path_out.LINETO, (OUTER_AMPLITUDE-INNER_AMPLITUDE, OUTER_AMPLITUDE-INNER_AMPLITUDE)),
    (Path_out.LINETO, (OUTER_AMPLITUDE, OUTER_AMPLITUDE-INNER_AMPLITUDE)),
    (Path_out.CLOSEPOLY, (OUTER_AMPLITUDE, OUTER_AMPLITUDE-INNER_AMPLITUDE)),
    ]
codes, verts = zip(*path_out_data)
path_out = mpath.Path(verts, codes)
patch_out = mpatches.PathPatch(path_out, facecolor='r', alpha=0.3)
ax.add_patch(patch_out)
plt.title('Square in a square in a square')

ax.grid()
ax.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

Do note I consider this off-topic for Code Review since I'm looking for extending my functionality, not just a re-write which is up to best-practices. I feel like I'm doing it completely the wrong way. First things first.

How should I draw polygons with a certain width using `matplotlib`, assuming the polygon will be surrounded on the outside with a band of the same form and at least the same width and completely filled on the inside?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly. Could you please clarify: a) Do you want to handle arbitrary polygons and not just rectangles? b) What is your input? The inner (green) polygon? c) What's the output? The red frame?

Comment: @hitzg a) Preferably arbitrary polygons, but it's fine if it only works on rectangles at first. b) `INNER_AMPLITUDE` and `OUTER_AMPLITUDE` are considered input, the script does not take arguments. Those are responsible for green (inner) and red (outer). c) The output is the white band between green and red.

Comment: ok, thanks. I'm a bit confused: I was under the impression that the white band doesn't *exist*. And if only `INNER_AMPLITUDE` and `OUTER_AMPLITUDE` are given, what defines the width of the red band?

Comment: @hitzg Techincally the white band doesn't exist, it only exists by reversing the picture. I'm interested in the bounds of the polygon, not the polygon itself. The width of the red band is largely irrelevant except I thought it would look better if the red band was somewhere along the size of the white band. It's width is defined by it's own amplitude and that of the inner square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handling polygons purely in matplotlib can be quite tedious. Luckily there is a very nice library for these kind of operations: [shapely](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html).
For your purposes the `parallel_offset` function is the way to go.
The bounds of the polygons which you're interested in, are defined by `ring1`, `ring2` and `ring3`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import shapely.geometry as sg
from descartes.patch import PolygonPatch

# if I understood correctly you mainly need the difference d here
INNER_AMPLITUDE = 0.1
OUTER_AMPLITUDE = 0.2
d = OUTER_AMPLITUDE - INNER_AMPLITUDE

# fix seed, for reproducability
np.random.seed(11111)

# a function to produce a "random" polygon
def random_polygon():
    nr_p = np.random.randint(7,15)
    angle = np.sort(np.random.rand(nr_p)*2*np.pi)
    dist = 0.3*np.random.rand(nr_p) + 0.5
    return np.vstack((np.cos(angle)*dist, np.sin(angle)*dist)).T

# your input polygon
p = random_polygon()

# create a shapely ring object
ring1 = sg.LinearRing(p)
ring2 = ring1.parallel_offset(d, 'right', join_style=2, mitre_limit=10.)
ring3 = ring1.parallel_offset(2*d, 'right', join_style=2, mitre_limit=10.)

# revert the third ring. This is necessary to use it to procude a hole
ring3.coords = list(ring3.coords)[::-1]

# inner and outer polygon
inner_poly = sg.Polygon(ring1)
outer_poly = sg.Polygon(ring2, [ring3])

# create the figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)

# convert them to matplotlib patches and add them to the axes
ax.add_patch(PolygonPatch(inner_poly, facecolor=(0,1,0,0.4),
    edgecolor=(0,1,0,1), linewidth=3))
ax.add_patch(PolygonPatch(outer_poly, facecolor=(1,0,0,0.4),
    edgecolor=(1,0,0,1), linewidth=3))

# cosmetics
ax.set_aspect(1)
plt.axis([-1.5, 1.5, -1.5, 1.5])
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: It took me a while to reproduce, but this works perfect :-)